# Calling Rspec with syntax like ruby -I

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to use https://github.com/rifraf/Vendorize which is run using a command like

```
D:\projects\SomeLibrary\lib>ruby -I..\..\Vendorize\lib -rvendorize some_lib.rb
```

It does something clever where it intercepts required files and logs them, but only the ones that get executed in your command line. On it's documentation pages it says

> You can run the program several times with different options if the
>   required files depend on the options.
>
> Or just run your tests…

I want to run all the tests with the -I function from the command line above, so that all the different avenues of code are run, and the libraries loaded (and logged). Given that I can run them like:

```
D:\projects\SomeLibrary\lib>rspec ..\spec\some_spec.rb
```

How do I do this? Thanks!

NB: I am a/ a ruby newbie and b/ running windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try writing something like this at the top of `some_spec.rb`:

```
require_relative '..\..\Vendorize\lib\vendorize'
```

You might need to change that a bit depending on what your working directory is.

Then just runs your specs with `rspec` as you normally do without any extra commands.

If that doesn't work, then locate the `rspec.rb` executable and run:

```
ruby -I..\..\Vendorize\lib -rvendorize path/to/rspec.rb ..\spec\some_spec.rb
```